# Convert long to int, keep positive/negative/0

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

I want to implement a `java.util.Comparator` with `Long`:

```
new Comparator<Long>() {
    public int compare(Long l1, Long l2) {
        // (*)
    }
}
```

I have a solution with operator `?:`:

```
return l1==l2 ? 0 : (l1>l2 ? 1 : -1);
```

But I wonder if there is any other way to implement it.

(I was trying `return (int)(l1-l2)`, but it's incorrect).

Comment: Why would you want to alter your implementation? It is correct.

Comment: `return (int)Math.signum(l1-l2)` ?

Comment: @assylias You're then converting a long to a double, and a double back to a int again. Also that solution might not be correct for all long's (e.g. return 0 on 2^60 and 2^60-1)

Comment: @dtech clearly not efficient, but was in response to "(I was trying return (int)(l1-l2), but it's incorrect)."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's easy - `Long` itself provides an implementation:

```
public int compare(Long l1, Long l2) {
    return l1.compareTo(l2);   
}
```

On the other hand, at that point I'm not sure why you've got a custom comparator at all...

EDIT: If you're *actually* comparing `long` values and you're using Java 1.7, you can use `Long.compare(long, long)`. Otherwise, go with your current implementation.

Comment: Thank you, it's a simplified demo of my real problem. But I just found, what I need to compare is `long`s, not `Long`s, so I have to still use `?:`

Comment: @FreeWind Java has autoboxing since 1.6 so it doesn't matter. long and Long can be used interchangedly in method signatures. Or you can just use `new Long(long value)`

Comment: Your answer is still the best for this question :)

Answer (score 2):

No, that is the only valid way to do so. This topic is already discussed a lot of times. Of course, `java.lang.Long` implements already a compareTo function, but it has exactly the same implementation as you have.

Comment: Finally I still use `?:`, but since in this question it's `Long`, so I have to choose JonSkeet's answer. Thank you!